# Pipe output with expect spawn

Tags: linux, bash, expect, spawn

I have script for copying some files by ssh to other server. I'm using tar for compressing files to on farchive and decompress it from stdout on other machine.

```
set timeout -1

# user info
set port [lindex $argv 0]
set login [lindex $argv 1]
set password [lindex $argv 3]
set host [lindex $argv 2]

#tar info
set sdir [lindex $argv 4]
set ddir [lindex $argv 5]

spawn tar cf - $sdir | ssh -p $port $login@$host tar xf - -C $ddir

expect "*?(yes/no)" {
    send "yes\r"
}

expect "*?assword" {
    send "$password\r"
}

expect "#" {
    send "ls $ddir -la\r"
}

expect "#" {
    send "exit\r"
}

interact
```

But '|' doesn't work with spawn. I tried to find any solution, but there no any suitable way for me. Can you give me an advice for this question?

Comment: Don't use expect for this. Set up ssh keys using `ssh-keygen` and `ssh-copy-id`

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I have a recommendation. As above said, using key based auth instead of password based is better for most cases.
Also, consider using Python for more complicated scripting instead of bash. Use the fabric module if possible, or just the standard library pexpect module.
Also consider using rsync with compression instead.

Sorry I don't have an answer for your specific question, but only recommendations on how I'd solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

"spawn" the shell

```
set timeout -1

# user info
set port [lindex $argv 0]
set login [lindex $argv 1]
set password [lindex $argv 3]
set host [lindex $argv 2]

#tar info
set sdir [lindex $argv 4]
set ddir [lindex $argv 5]

spawn $env(SHELL) 

expect "#" {
    send "(tar cf - \$sdir) | (ssh -p \$port \$login@\$host tar xf - -C \$ddir)\r"
} 

expect -re "(yes/no)" {
    send "yes\r"
}

expect -re "assword" {
    send "$password\r"
}

expect "#" {
    send "exit\r"
}

interact
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can't setup keys, you can put the "tar ... | ssh ..." line into another script and call it with spawn, just pass the required parameter

.i.e:

```
spawn anotherscript.bash $sdir $port $login $host
```

You got the idea.

Comment: Good old heredocs